# How do I hide code/files on my website?

Tags: javascript, web

Currently, I have a website: http://hitsujistories.com

There is some javascript running in the body of the index.html that makes a bunch of particles on the screen. I want to keep this code private, but if you got to http://hitsujistories.com/canvas.js the code is openly available for anyone to see. How can I hide this file?

I tried to put the file in a password protected folder, but it didn't work because whenever I tried to go on the website (index.html) and it called for the javascript file, it would require the password.

Comment: You can't hide it. In fact it's downloaded to users PC anyway. You can only obfuscate the code, but even that does not fully protect your code.

Comment: JavaScript needs to be interpreted by the browser and as such needs to be visible. However, you can obfuscate/minify your JavaScript so that it becomes practically unreadable.

Comment: A quick google finds almost identical code to the canvas.js on your site:
https://codepen.io/kzgill1217/pen/xdQXXx/

So why bother trying to hide it?

Comment: Because this is example code for the code I'm intending to upload. @ChrisNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not hide your JS as it is received and interpreted on users side. You can use tools to minify your JS and make it less readable and also reduce file size.

Comment: just google for "js minify", they all do pretty much the same

Comment: @BrandonFinley: That's explicitly off-topic for this site. Search "minify javascript"; I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: This site is very harsh. I get snapped at and down voted for asking questions. Not complaining just an observation. @ShadowRanger